# How to guarantee the existence of static members in a type?

Tags: c#, .net

Since C# has not provided support of static members for interfaces It is very hard to guarantee of existence of certain static members in class. I know that there is abstract class-ancestor for it, but I can't use it because in such case static members will be the same. For example:

```
class StaticClass
{
    protected static int _secretNumber = 10;

    public static int SecretNumber { get { return StaticClass._secretNumber; } }
}

class SomeData : StaticClass
{
    SomeData() { SomeData._secretNumber = 25; }
}

class SomeData2 : StaticClass
{
    SomeData2() { SomeData2._secretNumber = 50; }
}
```

In such case StaticClass.SecretNumber = SomeData.SecretNumber = SomeData2.SecretNumber = 10.
What I must to do in order to guarantee that a type contains a own static member?

Comment: Why do you need to guarantee that? Moreover, if you are programming against an interface you won't be able to access this static member. What's your goal here?

Comment: My reason is very apparent: interfaces are not supported static members, but I need to work with different types only through interface or abstract class and using static members of them.

Comment: Ummm... didn't you say yourself that interfaces do not support static members and base classes would share the member => you need to do what you already know is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you can't. And why would you want to? To access the fields you have to refer to them directly (unless you're using reflection), so the compiler will check for you.

Why do you want to do this?

If you just want subclasses to assign the variable, then that's a contract of the class you simply can't specify in code. Use documentation to explain that subclasses have to assign a particular number to this variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

First off, "protected static" is unsuggested, so I'd avoid it.

Secondly, why not defining "secretNumber" as instance, instead of static?

I don't see any valid reason for having "static interfaces", unless you will play with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: I think what you are proposing has a very distinct smell**

For the sake of the exercise he's a generic solution to part of the problem. Is is possible to do part of what you wish. It's a bit of trickery to accomplish something I think at best will be a design error. But as a code exercise that kind of code is fun to write.

The below code does not require the Derived to initialize the static field but ensures that any derived class will have it's own instance. however when using the static member you still have to access it through the concrete class. So I can't see how it's really useful

```
class BaseClass<T, K> where T : BaseClass<T, K>
{
    protected static K _secret;

    public static K Secret { get { return _secret; } }
}

class Derived : BaseClass<Derived, int>
{
    static Derived()
    {
        _secret = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: But again, all derived classes will share the `static` member.

Comment: @jon not really since each derived class is passing it self to instantiate the generic based class they get their own static instance.